# The "Default Zoom Level" Mouse Button

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse, zooming, mousewheel

Many mice and keyboards have "zoom" buttons on them. These almost always generate Ctrl+Mouse Wheel messages to the applications, so they are easily accounted for by us programmers.

But my current Logitech mouse has an additional feature. The zoom wheel indeed sends Ctrl+Mouse Wheel messages when scrolled (or, actually, tilted), but when I *depress* the zoom wheel, most programs restore the zoom level to the default, i.e. 100 %. What kind of message does the mouse send to the application in this case? I cannot find a suitable [virtual key code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx) for it.

I should probably say that I have tried to capture this event. In my Delphi application, I wrote handlers for the `KeyDown`, `MouseDown`, and `MouseWheel` events, but non of them are triggered by this mysterious button.

Applications that support this button:

- Google Chrome 5.0.375.127
- Microsoft Word 2010

Applications that seem not to support this button:

- Microsoft WordPad in Windows 7
- Microsoft Paint in Windows 7

Comment: I always thought it was VK_MBUTTON but some applications are now beginning to use Ctrl-0 for the "default zoom" function.

Comment: Are you sure that the application is seeing the key or is Windows grabbing it and sending a synthetic event? Google doesn't even think Chrome handles Ctrl-Middle on Windows and has recently changed their Linux version to ignore it: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated shortcut key-stroke or Windows message.  Odds are pretty good that the mouse helper has specific awareness of the process that has the focus.  And generates the specific command that this program needs to reset the zoom, possibly a WM_COMMAND message.  Use a tool like Microsoft's Spy++ to see what messages are generated, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech M570 and downloaded 'set point'.
Not all mice / trackballs have this feature, dead giveaway is having a 'forward / back' button on your mouse or trackball. If you can get 'set point', there are programmable button / wheel options.

1. find your mouse or trackball on their product page, then,  > support > (your mouse), > downloads
2. If your device can use 'set point', see download button window on the left, insure your Windows version.
3. Select 'set point'
4. at the bottom of the window, hit download, go through wizard steps. Download may be fast or take a while.
5. If it looks like it successfully downloaded, > control panel > mouse. You will see 'mouse properties', look for set point tab.
6. Try programming 'ctrl' on your 'depress' mouse wheel or 'tilt' button. 
   I'm a writer, I love my M570 wireless trackball!